# Extract substructure from a text file using bash or python

Tags: python, bash

I have a huge text file, which follows the structure:

```
SET
TAG1
...
...
SET
...
SET
TAG2
...
...
SET
...
...
```

I would like to extract for a specific TAG, (i.e. TAG54) its individual "substructure", which would be

```
SET
TAG54
...
...
SET
```

Each substructure, for a given TAG_i contains always:

first line:SET
second line:TAG_i (in this case TAG54)
an arbitrary number of lines 
last line:SET

I wonder what would be the best way to do this, whether in bash or python, so for a given TAG, one can "extract" this substructure.

Thanks

Comment: Not a very good solution, but you can use a my bad regex in python: /TAG\d+?(.+?)SET/gsm
There is a better way to do newlines, but the regex tool I was using doesn't like them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python approach: you pass in the open file handle as the first argument, the tag number as second argument, and get back as the result a list of the relevant lines (including newline characters), or an empty line if the tag is not found in the file:

```
def lookfor(f, tagnum):
  tag = 'TAG%s\n' % tagnum
  for line in f:
    if line == tag:
       break
  else: # file finished, tag not found
    return []
  result = ['SET\n', tag]
  for line in f:
    result.append(line)
    if line == 'SET\n':
        break
  return result
```

This should be reasonably well-performing.  If you want other forms of arguments and/or results, it shouldn't be hard to tweak accordingly, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If your system's `grep` supports `-P` for perl regexp:

```
grep -P 'SET\nTAG54\n[.\n]*\nSET' file.txt
```

Comment: hi, it does no work. can you tell me what each part does? thanks a lot

Comment: `grep` is a search tool; the `-P` option makes `grep` use a perl-type regexp (your system may not support `-P`); `'SET\nTAG54\n[.\n]*\nSET'` is the regexp to match: `SET` followed by a newline, followed by `TAG54` and a newline, then some arbitrary number (`*`) of arbitrary characters and/or newlines (`[.\n]`), a newline, and `SET`; `file.txt` is the name of the file to search.

Answer (score 0):

```
csplit -f tags input.txt '%^TAG54$%-1' '/^SET$/+1' '%.*%' '{*}'
```

Answer (score 0):

gawk:

```
BEGIN {
  state=0
}

state==0 && $0=="TAG54" {
  print "SET"
  state=1
}

state==1 {
  print
}

state==1 && $0=="SET" {
  exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -vRS="SET" '/TAG54/{print RT$0RT}' file
SET
TAG54
...
...
SET
```

if you are doing it with shell scripting, pass your shell variable to `awk` using `-v`. eg

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "what's your tag? " tag
awk -vRS="SET" -vt="$tag" '$0~tag{print RT$0RT}' file
```

Comment: hi, your approach is really nice and simple! I forgot to mention that I also need the lines wiht "SET" at the beginning and end of the file, but I will do by myself. thanks